# Why are C's arrays first dimension ignored by the compiler as a function parameter?

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-construction

I know that in C if we were to write:

```
void myFunction(int x[30]) // 30 is ignored by the compiler

void myFunction(int x[][30]) // 30 is not ignored here but if I put say '40' in the first dimension
                             // it would be ignored.
```

Why is it that the first dimension is ignored by the compiler?

Comment: C arrays do not perform any bounds-checking, so what would it mean for the first dimension to *not* be ignored? What would the compiler do with it?

Comment: @ruakh Circular argument. If the type was matched then you wouldn't be able to pass arrays of different incompatible sizes. Also,when there is size information, you can get the array length by using the `sizeof` operator.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I'm not sure what you mean by "circular argument". C arrays *never* perform any bounds-checking, even when declared and used in the same function. (Your other examples are good ones, though.)

Comment: @ruakh Sorry, not a circular argument. What I meant is that, despite the absence of bounds checking, the compiler could, for example, issue an error if you pass an array that doesn't match the length. Instead, the language allows you to put in a size, and then adjusts the type to pointer anyway. That is quite confusing!

Answer (score 3):

```
void myFunction(int x[30])
```

is equivalent to

```
void myFunction(int *x)
```

i.e, when arrays are used as parameters to function then array names are treated by compiler as *pointer to first element of array*. In this case the length of first dimension is of no use.
This way you must have to pass size of array explicitly to the function.

Answer (score 3):

In the context of a function parameter declaration, both `T a[]` and `T a[N]` are interpreted as `T *a`; that is, all three declare `a` as a *pointer* to `T`.  This goes along with the fact that, unless it is the operand of the `sizeof`or the unary `&` operator, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and its value will be the address of the first element of the array.

It's not that the dimension is being ignored, it's that it's not meaningful in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Since the C function does not check whether an array reference is in bounds, and since it does not allocate any space for it, the dimension has no use there.  It only calculates an offset from the pointer (start of the array) and it already knows how to do that (based on the size of int).

When you specify more than one dimension, it needs to know that dimension only so it can calculate the proper offset for an array reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ignored/useless according to the language.  It may be ignored by the compiler.

If inside myFunction, you write:

```
      ... x[29] ...
```

you get a valid program.

If you write

```
      ... x[30] ...
```

your program has undefined behavior.  The compiler may or may not check for this.

The fact that compiler can't always check everything is the price one pays for having a language as close to the machine as C is.

Comment: And even though the compiler won't check parameters passed to the function, it communicates information to a programmer reading the function signature -- this function expects (the address of) an array of (at least) 30 integers as the first parameter, not just a pointer to an integer.

Comment: True but the question is why the *compiler* "ignores" this value.

Comment: But the size *is* ignored by the compiler in this case, with a parameter of type `T t[N]` being adjusted to "qualified pointer to
type T". There are no qualifiers between the `[]` so it is just plain `T* t`. The compiler ignores the size because the language specification says there is no size to consider.